# not able to increase the height and width of modal pop

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to increase the height and width of the dialog box shown in the below example
trying to find, is that controlled by css or any properties of this dialog box
https://stackblitz.com/angular/pakbybeedmp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-data-example.ts

I am using Angular 8 for the same
I tried updating the matdialogconfig parameters, I am not able to see the reflection of parameters on Dialog box

Any suggestion please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When opening the dialog, you can specify height and width:

```
this.dialog.open(DialogDataExampleDialog, {
      height: "500px",
      width: "500px",
      data: {
        animal: "panda"
      }
    });
```

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7nwm7j?file=src/app/dialog-data-example.ts)

Comment: Its working fine in stackblitz
But when I am implementing in my project,its getting to extreme left, even I am not able to read the contents in the new pop up..

Comment: then you must have something else which interferes, I can't help if you don't identify it \ reproduce it